# Print floating point numbers with tabulation in python?

Tags: python, formatting

I'm trying to print a nice table of numbers by this code line:

```
print '{0:}  {1:.5g}  {2:.5g}  {3:.5g}  {4:.5g}'.format((i-1),a,b,p,fp)
```

Where *a*, *b*, *p* and *fp* are floating points and i happens to be an integer.

However I'm getting this message:

> `ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'`

All mentioned variables are defined in this function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from sympy import *
from numpy import *
from scipy import *

def biseccion(fx,x,a,b,tolerancia,iteracionesMaximas):
    i = 1
    p = 0
    fa = fx.subs(x,a)

    while i<=iteracionesMaximas:
        t = (b-a)/2
        p = a+t
        fp = fx.subs(x,p)

        if fp == 0 or t < tolerancia:
            print "Se encontró la raíz y=%f luego de %i iteraciones"%(p,(i-1))
            return 

        i += 1

        if fa * fp > 0:
            a = p
        else:
            b = p

        print '{0:}  {1:.5g}  {2:.5g}  {3:.5g}  {4:.5g}'.format((i-1),a,b,p,fp)

    print 'El método falló luego de {iteraciones} iteraciones'.format(iteraciones=iteracionesMaximas)
```

What's the good way to print with format in my Python 2.7.5+ version?

Comment: The error clearly suggests that at least one of `a`,`b`,`p` or `fp` is a string not float.

Comment: Try to print the type of those variables before that line.

Comment: They're not string, any of them:

<type 'int'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?